# Dynamic change of html attribute values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There is a template for creating buttons, the number may be different. It is necessary that each button opens a block when pressed. I tried using JS scripts, they correctly set the id of the drop-down element, but I can't change the link, as a result, either all the elements open, or all the buttons open only one section.

```
<a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#" data-bs-target="#target">{{profile.profile}}</a>
<div class="collapse target" id="target">
  <div class="card card-body"><a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3">Some text1</a></div>
  <div class="card card-body"><a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3">Some text1</a></div>
</div>
```

I want to change `data-bs-target` values, but after first element the script breaks and I get the same values

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.collapse').each(function(index) {
    // получаем текущий id элемент
    var id = $(this).prop('id');

    $(this).prop('id', id + index);

    $(this).parent().find('[href="#' + id + '"]').attr('href', '#' + id + index);
    $(this).parent().find('[data-bs-target="#' + id + '"]').attr('data-bs-target', '#' + id + index);

  });
</script>
```

The result:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#" data-bs-target="#target0" aria-expanded="true">Some text</a>
<div class="target collapse show" id="target0" style="">
  <div class="card card-body"><a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3">Some text1</a></div>
  <div class="card card-body"><a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3">Some text1</a></div>
</div>


<a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#" data-bs-target="#target0" aria-expanded="true">Some text</a>
<div class="collapse target" id="target1">
```

Help me find mistakes pls

Comment: It seems to me that `$('.collapse').each()` runs against *all* the existing `.collapse` elements. So you're not going `1->2->3->4->...` but instead `1->2->4->8`. That fact, combined with the fact you're calculating the next id by doing `(new)id = (old)id + index`, means you're getting collisions.

Comment: There's many ways of fixing it; For one you should probably only run the function against the first `.collapse` instead of *each*. I'm not a jquery user but a quick websearch shows that that probably means using `.first()` (or `[0]`) (before the `.each()` function i suppose). That should fix the `1->2->4->8` part of the problem.

Comment: @Raxi, the id's in div collapse works correctly, it increases the id, but I need to change ```data-bs-target``` value, so I can open that list (If I am expressing myself correctly)

Comment: It should only work fine for the first few orso at the moment, due to the `1->2->4->8` thing. But either way, if you were to fix the problem with `each()` running multiple times (per activation) then the id's might work fine; i'm not really sure what sort of indexes jquery uses in each

Comment: 1 problem: `find('[href="#' + id + '"]')` never matches anything, because the only `href` is `#`.  I think that should be `href="#target"`? About the rest, it is hard to help without seeing the code which actuall adds your buttons, how do you do that?  And do you really want to run for *every* `.collapse`, every time you add a button? Shouldn't it just run for the last one?